# Jmeter load requests failure for AWS API Gateway + Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, aws-lambda, load-testing, aws-api-gateway

I need to load test a node js based AWS lambda function behind AWS API Gateway. But If I try basic test with 1000 users + 60 seconds, 10-20 % requests get failed with error

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
```

When I try same node js function on local server with node js / mongo db, It allow 5K..10K requests without failures.

Node js script inserting a big packet json data (approx 100K) into mongo db.

These are configurations

```
Jmeter : connect timeout : 10000 millseconds
AWS Lamdba RAM allocated : 512M 
AWS Lamdba Timeout : 30 seconds
```

UPDATE : 
After updating heap to 2GB, I am able to hit 1K requests, but now it failing (40% requests) at 5K requests.

Comment: It sounds like CloudFront (which is front of API Gateway) is closing connections and your application is attempting to reuse them. 1. Do you have appropriate limits in your account for this test? 2. How is your JMeter test managing connections?

Comment: looks like JMeter side hits port limit. Check this: lognormal.com/blog/2012/09/27/linux-tcpip-tuning

Comment: Make sure you have AWS confirmation you're allowed to proceed with the test. Load test is not security scan but can cause DOS, so I believe users are obliged to receive the green light.

Comment: @Putnik, AWS have account  limits (throttle) for handling this. I did not get any throttle in cloud watch, Load test itself should not be the reason.

Comment: if you don't see the throttling in AWS docs, that: 1) doesn't mean it doesn't exist (I've personally seen undocumented throttling on the instance network throughput) 2) may just mean you didn't yet reach the right place in the docs to find it (sometimes AWS docs are quite hazy)

Comment: and finally, check this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

you may see something familiar

Comment: @YuriG, sorry for late reply, Idid not mean that I did not found on docs, I means I did get throttle stats is zero on cloudwatch.

Comment: Then it might be lambda itself. Mind that it is not "just" the shared resource, like EC2 instance (to some extent, it's a predictable amount of resources you can count on) - but the ultimate one. You hardly can predict anything there. So the only thing I can suggest there - add detailed tracing to your Lambdas, and analyze the output to pinpoint the circumstances it fails under. Even if the point of failure is not there - you'd know it for sure.